# How to find the list of parent objects by passing list of child objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entity classes namely Parent and Child

child class

```
public class Child{
@Id
@Column(name="childId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int childId;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name = "childId")
public Parent parent;
```

and following is the parent class

```
public class Parent
    @Id
    @Column(name="parentId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer parentId;
```

I have a DAO method as follow

```
public List<parent> getParent(String executionStatus) {
        List<parent> parentList = null;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session =sessionFactory.openSession();
            parentList = session.createQuery(
                    "from parent where executionStatus='"+executionStatus+"'     )
                    .list();


        }
        return parentList;
    }
```

I am accessing this method from service class as

```
    List<parent> parentList=userDAO.getParent("test");
```

My question is how would I retrieve the list of child class by having the list of parent class

Answer (score 0):

You can add mapping to Parent as follows

```
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name="parentId")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer parentId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<Child> children
}
```

Also i'd suggest changing `@JoinColumn(name = "childId")` to `@JoinColumn(name = "parentId")` above many-to-one mapping in Child

Comment: why do I need to modify parent??

Comment: You dont _need_, but its common practice to name foreign key column after the table it references.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to have an mapping from Parent to Child like below:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Child> children;
```

Then:

```
 parentList = session.createQuery(
                    "select p from Parent p join p.children c where p.executionStatus='"+executionStatus+"')
                    .list();
```

Comment: how to pass list of child objects

Comment: set child list to parent?

Answer (score 0):

YOu can add join and retrieve children

```
childList = session.createQuery(
                    "from child c INNER JOIN c.parent p where p.executionStatus='"+executionStatus+"'     )
                    .list();
```

Comment: I have list of child objects. So will your answer work?